# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

Title says it all really, I'm getting this error and I just don't know what to put before the & to make it work any ideas?

I only used the part of the header and cpp files i thought were necessary

header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#ifndef INDEXLIST_H
#define INDEXLIST_H

template <class T>
class indexList
{
 public:
  //constuctor, default
  //Descriptions: Initializes numberOfElement to 0
  //              Initializes maxSize to 100
  //Parameters:   none
  //Return:       none

  indexList(int size = 10);

  //copy constructor
  indexList(const indexList &rhs);

  //destructor
  ~indexList();

  //assignment operator
  indexList &operator=(const indexList &rhs);
```

cpp:

```
//assignment operator
template <class T>
 // error occurs on the line below
indexList &indexList::operator=(const indexList &rhs)
{
  if(*this != rhs)
    {
      delete [] list;
      numberOfElement = rhs.numberOfElement;
      maxSize = rhs.maxSize;
      list = new T[maxSize];
      for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
        list[i] = rhs.list[i];
        }

      return *this;

    }
```

Comment: Which line is indicated for the error?

Comment: the third line of the cpp

Answer (score 0):

Missing a couple `<T>` from the syntax:

```
//assignment operator
template <class T>
indexList<T> &indexList<T>::operator=(const indexList &rhs)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, this definition, like all template functions, should probably be defined in the header file.

Comment: is it not defined under //assignment operator

Comment: Yes, but watch where you need to use `indexList<T>`, not just `indexList`.